# Gremlin Python "name 'V' is not defined" when using coalesce to chain insert edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I am trying to batch insert edges using `coalesce` . And I was trying to follow this format for batch edge insert that I found on [Neptune DB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-efficient-upserts.html):

```
g.V('v-1')
 .outE('KNOWS')
 .hasId('e-1')
 .fold()
 .coalesce(unfold(),
           V('v-1').addE('KNOWS')
                   .to(V('v-2'))
                   .property(id, 'e-1'))
 .V('v-3')
 .outE('KNOWS')
 .hasId('e-2').fold()
 .coalesce(unfold(),
           V('v-3').addE('KNOWS')
                   .to(V('v-4'))
                   .property(id, 'e-2'))
 .V('v-5')
 .outE('KNOWS')
 .hasId('e-3')
 .fold()
 .coalesce(unfold(),
           V('v-5').addE('KNOWS')
                   .to(V('v-6'))
                   .property(id, 'e-3'))
 .next()
```

When I used this format in my Python script, I get the error that  `name 'V' is not defined`. I know Gremlin Python is slightly different to the Gremlin language. But I couldn't find documentation on this.

I tried adding double underscore in front of V like this:

```
g.V('v-1')
 .outE('KNOWS')
 .hasId('e-1')
 .fold()
 .coalesce(unfold(),
           __.V('v-1').addE('KNOWS')
                   .to(__.V('v-2'))
                   .property(id, 'e-1'))
...
 .next()
```

but I got this error `Received error message '{'requestId': 'None', 'status': {'code': 499, 'message': '{"detailedMessage":"Invalid OpProcessor requested [null]","code":"UnsupportedOperationException"}', 'attributes': {}}, 'result': {'meta': {}, 'data': None}}'`

I connect to gremlin like this:

```
def get_connection(endpoint): 
   return DriverRemoteConnection(endpoint, 'g')

def get_graph(connection): 
   return traversal().withRemote(connection) 
   
connex = get_connection(neptune_endpoint) 
g = get_graph(connex)
```

**Edit**
The solution was to have `__.V` instead of `V` and change `id` to `T.id`.
Thanks @Kelvin Lawrence for the help and prompt response!

Comment: How are you creating the connection to the server? That error seems to indicate the request that was sent was not formatted correctly.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Apologies for the ugly format. This graph is connected to a neptune db. I am able run other commands like inserting vertices.

Comment: If you add it to the question you will be able to format it. Using `T.id` instead of just `id` may be needed also. In Python `id` is a built in function.

Comment: I've updated the post to show how I connected to the server.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Thank you for your suggestion. `T.id` instead of `id` fixed the issue.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer in case others run into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Python client, to work around reserved word conflicts and other issues, a few things are different. As you noticed, an anonymous traversal (a traversal nested inside another one) needs to use the "double underscore" notation as in `__.V('1')`.

Similarly, there are several built in functions in Python that collide with Gremlin names. One such is `id`. To work around this you can just specify `T.id` instead.